# Is it safe to use compress algorithm to GPU attack?

Tags: android, algorithm, security, hash, gpu

I want to make 256bit message digest from user password.

I know Argon2 is recommended for security but it is not supported for Android device so far.

So, I came up with another method below.

1. Encrypt big random data, which is so big that GPU cannot remain the data on SRAM, with some algorithm(e.g AES) by user password.
2. Encode the encrypted data with Zip algorithm.
3. Get message digest of the zip data with SHA256

I think Zip encoding is the one of the worst algorithm for GPU,
because it processes just 1 bit each and have many If branches.
Not parallelizable.

Zip is lossless compression, so generated data in step2 is unique with user password.

Considering GPU architecture, which takes many clock cycles when execute If branch,
I think encoding Zip with GPU is slower than with CPU.

How about this?
Safe?

I'm just a beginner for security.

Could any one please assess this method?

Comment: Should probably ask this on crypto.stackexchange.com instead ...

Comment: `libsodium` has Argon2, and [there are three cited `libsodium` implementations for Android](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/bindings_for_other_languages/).

Comment: Do not create your own cryptographic methods. ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.

Comment: I try to use libsodium in this case, and try to ask this method on crypto.stackexchange.com just an idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Comment: Now that GPGPU has been very developed, PBKDF2 is too weak.  Bcrypt is much secure than PBKDF2 but I need just 256bit hash.

Comment: Actually the current [DRAFT NIST Special Publication 800-63B Digital Authentication Guideline](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html)  recommends PBKDF2. *"Verifiers SHALL store memorized secrets in a form that is resistant to offline attacks. Secrets SHALL be hashed with a salt value using an approved hash function such as PBKDF2 as described in [SP800-132]"*